# val() function does not work in html field which is type number

Tags: jquery

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_call.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{dist_task_id:task_id},
    success: function(result){
        //var rs = result;
        alert(result);//working
        alert(rs);//working
        $(".wtime").val(result);//not working
        $(".wtime").val(rs);//not working
    }
});
```

**Html**

```
<input class="form-control comm wtime" type="number" step="any" required id="latbox" value="" min="0" max="20" name="w_time[]">
```

I have html field which type is number. val() function can't set value in that field.
Why???

Comment: can you share htmls as well?

Comment: <input class="form-control comm wtime" type="number" step="any" required id="latbox" value="" min="0" max="20" name="w_time[]">

Comment: i think something else is causing the problem

Comment: are you sure that the result is a number?

Comment: If type number replace by text then work......

Comment: then the result is not a number type number inly accepts number no other. make sure you return a number it will work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure "Result" is of type interger, then make sure it's within your min and max properties in your HTML.

```
$(".wtime").val(parseInt(result))
```